# how to use optional flag in fish

Tags: fish

I'm building a CLI tasks utility, (A cheap version of taskwarrior).
I want to add some optional flags, such as -n

```
else if [ $cmd = 'delete' ]
argparse 'n/index'=? -- $argv
sed -i "$_flag_index d" ~/.tasks/data/Tdo.csv
```

but this gives an error

> ~/.tasks/run.sh (line 14): No matches for wildcard “'n/index'=?”. See `help expand`.
> argparse 'n/index'=? -- $argv

I'm unable to understand the correct usage of optional flags, and I've not been able to find enough resources, the fish shell documentation isn't sufficient for a novice in shell scripting given lack of examples.

How to accept an optional argument n/index, and further execute some code if the argument has been given, and something else otherwise, and is it possible to add integer constraints on optional arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `help expand` like fish told you?

The unquoted `?` is being handled as a globbing character. Use `'n/index=?'`

```
$ set argv --index=10

$ argparse 'n/index'=? -- $argv
fish: No matches for wildcard ''n/index'=?'. See `help expand`.
argparse --ignore-unknown 'n/index'=? -- $argv
                          ^

# quote the whole thing
#          v         v
$ argparse 'n/index=?' -- $argv

$ set -S _flag_index
$_flag_index: set in local scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$_flag_index[1]: |10|
```

Comment: A followup, when I don't pass this flag, shouldn't the variable _flag_index be empty or not defined, but in my case it says its value is 2

Comment: I've observed that if I use set -e _flag_index before writing argparse, things seem to work the way I expect

Comment: argparse sets variables in the current scope, so if you're running it from the interactive command line, then yes the variables will persist. If you run argparse in a script or in a function, then the variables will be in a separate scope and won't exist when you run argparse.